# Flask Socket-IO - force long polling

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

On PythonAnywhere, WebSockets are not supported. Flask-SocketIO can use long polling as an alternative.

Do you need to force long polling, and if you do, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is your friend:

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_socketio.SocketIO

```py
socketio = SocketIO(allow_upgrades=False)
```